# Creating a non-web-view-based sign-in screen for Microsoft SkyDrive

Tags: rest, ios5, user-interface, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement a sign in view like the one displayed below to allow users to sign into their Microsoft Live account and then allow the app to pull down their SkyDrive data.

[image: Sign-in Page Example]

I have been reading the API documentation at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx#objective_c) and it seems that the documentation is centered on you using a standard web UI login form which I would like to avoid (pictured below).

[image: Standard Page Example]

So I am looking for documentation or an example of implementing a custom login form to login to windows live to get SkyDrive data. Any information would be extremely helpful as I am pretty stuck.

Note: There is also an issue open on [github](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/issues/4) regarding the this same topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging I discovered that microsoft will only allow you to log in using OAuth 2.0 through their interface (pictured above). What I originally wanted goes completely against the design of their SDK and isn't/wont be supported.

According to an issue posted on [github](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/issues/4), there may eventually be a way to allow authentication through the Skydrive iOS app. As of now however, there is only one way to authenticate, through their SDK or API.

This is also stated in the documentation:

```
Your app must initiate the sign-in process by contacting the Live Connect authorization web service.
```

Resources:

- [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx)
- [Github Issue](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/issues/4)
- [LiveSDK-iOS](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS)

Comment: That realy sucks to know that because when you using the javascript API, it pop-ups a window that will be blocked by a popup blocker so the user have to accept it first and must reload the page. Silly and outdated technique if you ask me.